# Selenium: When new IWebDriver is created, browser launches then closes then relaunches a new session

Tags: c#, visual-studio, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Firefox and the icon will appear in the taskbar for half a second before closing. Then Firefox will launch again with the URL

about:blank&utm_content=firstrun

(Even though homepage is set to Google).

Could this be a environment variable issue? I haven't touched the path.

Basically, this is blocking me because the other statements will run into NoSuchElementException...

This is my code:

```
        using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
 using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
 using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

        namespace HomeAuto {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.trademe.co.nz");
                    SelectElement categories = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("SearchType")));
                    categories.SelectByValue("202");
                    IWebElement searchBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("searchString"));
                    searchBox.SendKeys("Some game");
                    searchBox.Submit();

                    driver.Close();

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue occurs even if I comment everything below the constructor. I've tried WaitForElement instead of the sleeper as well but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Discovered issue was in the url - even if browser can navigate without the protocol URI.

Everything works fine if the navigation method is changed to:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.trademe.co.nz");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little bit more @Lionfish. I'm having a similar issue when running my script, once Firefox opens it has the URL:  about:blank&utm_content=firstrun. I've run the exact same script using the PhantomJS and it works great, but Firefox gives this error.